# How can I connect REST API (Java) from QlikView?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I want to connect REST API from QlikView and create chart/table view based on the JSON response from the REST call.

Instead of connecting MySQL datasource and database **Is it possible to connect REST API and get the JSON and then generate chart/table view?**

Answer (score 1):

yes you need to download and install Qlikview Rest connector from downloads in Qlikview support page https://us-d.demo.qlik.com/download/.

Here is direct link to latest version 2.11 https://da3hntz84uekx.cloudfront.net/RESTConnector/2.11/0/_MSI/QlikRestConnector_setup.exe